# Помогите настроить Gitolite SSH+HTTP

Tags: apache, git, http

Сервер `ubuntu 14.04`
По `SSH` все отлично работaет. Нужно настроить `HTTP`

Делаю все по мануалу http://gitolite.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html

В верх файла `.gitolite.rc` добавил строчку

```
$ENV{PATH} .= ":/home/git/bin";
```

После этого создал папки

```
install -d -m 0755 -o git -g git /var/www/bin
install -d -m 0755 -o www-data-g www-data /var/www/git
```

Создал файл `gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh` по пути `/var/www/bin` содержимым

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Suexec wrapper for gitolite-shell
#

export GIT_PROJECT_ROOT="/home/git/repositories"
export GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME="/home/git"

exec ${GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME}/gitolite-source/src/gitolite-shell
```

Добавил файл `192.168.196.133`  в папке `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` содержимым

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName        192.168.196.133
    ServerAlias       git
    ServerAdmin       you@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/git
    <Directory /var/www/git>
        Options       None
        AllowOverride none
        Order         allow,deny
        Allow         from all
    </Directory>

    SuexecUserGroup git git
    ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/
    ScriptAlias /gitmob/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/

    <Location /git>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        Require valid-user
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache/git.passwd
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Сделал

```
$ sudo a2ensite 192.168.196.133
```

Затем добавил пользователя `www-data` в группу `git`

```
# sudo usermod -a -G git www-data
```

В конфигурации файла `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` добавил R = daemon к нужному репозиторию

```
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   admin
        R       =   daemon

repo    testing
        RW+     =   @all
```

После проделанных манипуляций пытаюсь склонировать репозиторий на клиенте

```
git clone http://192.168.196.133/gitolite-admin
```

Ошибка

```
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
fatal: repository 'http://192.168.196.133/gitolite-admin/' not found
```

Команда `cat /etc/group` показывает

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog,gitroot
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:gitroot
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:gitroot
audio:x:29:
dip:x:30:gitroot
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:gitroot
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
libuuid:x:101:
netdev:x:102:
crontab:x:103:
syslog:x:104:
fuse:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
mlocate:x:107:
ssh:x:108:
landscape:x:109:
gitroot:x:1000:
lpadmin:x:110:gitroot
sambashare:x:111:gitroot
ssl-cert:x:112:
git:x:1001:www-data
```

Comment: а что не в порядке с предыдущим вашим вопросом [Gitolite работа по SSH и HTTP одновременно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460349/178576)?

Comment: там не задействован gitolite. Я могу clone/push по http все кому угодно. А я хочу что бы права на эти действия по HTTP раздавать через gitolite. Нашел мануал http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#ssh-and-http. Но не силен в apache вот и никак не могу найти помощи все отсылают к документации

Comment: *у меня /usr/lib/git-core* и *у меня папка /opt вообще пустая* — там же просто примеры приведены. подставьте в примеры свои актуальные значения.

Comment: *у меня нет такого поля* — вероятно, конфигурацию библиотека *suexec* черпает из упомянутого в выводе каталога: `/etc/apache2/suexec/`.

Comment: хорошо тогда что должно быть в /opt/ если у меня все репозитории находятся в /home/git/repositories

Comment: ничего там и не должно быть. в тех примерах, где упоминается каталог `/opt/git`, подставляйте актуальное значение: `/home/git`, как я понимаю.

Comment: Проделал все что в вопросе но не работает

Answer (score 1):

> `git clone http://192.168.196.133/gitolite-admin`

судя по приведённой конфигурации *apache*, *url* должен начинаться с `/git`.

т.е., вероятно, так:

```
$ git clone http://192.168.196.133/git/gitolite-admin
```